# GeoPandas do not save the full geometry when using to_file

Tags: python, duplicates, save, shapefile, geopandas

I have created a function that suppose to drop duplicate geometry from polygon layer and the nsave it as shapefile.
The function works but I have realized that the polygons are not save correctly and I get lines.
When I checked how to polygons are saved , I have found out that the polygons string is not being save correctly and for that reason I can't get the shape properly.

This is how it hapenned.

First I have created the function:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd

#variable to define


file_location=r'data/ABCD.csv'
crs_s='epsg:4326'

geometry_column='GEOMETRY'

result_dest='shape/ABCD.shp'



def unique_geometry(gdf,file_location,crs_s,geometry_column,result_dest):
    gdf = gpd.read_file(file_location)
    gdf.crs=crs_file
    print('original length of the dataframe is: {}'.format(len(gdf)))
    gdf.drop_duplicates(subset=geometry_column,inplace=True)
    print('Total unique geometris: {}'.format(len(gdf)))
    gdf.to_file(result_dest)
    return gdf

unique_geometry(gdf,file_location,crs_file,geometry_column,result_dest)    
   
>>>
original length of the dataframe is: 1006
Total unique geometris: 479
```

Now when I print one value from the geometry column:

```
gdf.iloc[0,2]

>>>'MULTIPOLYGON(((-51.71916 -12.36817,-51.71903 -12.36821,-51.71906 -12.36936,-51.71906 -12.37198,-51.71924 -12.37435,-51.71916 -12.37494,-51.72185 -12.37441,-51.72488 -12.37372,-51.72539 -12.37355,-51.72615 -12.37306,-51.72612 -12.37264,-51.726 -12.37222,-51.72588 -12.37203,-51.72578 -12.37175,-51.72565 -12.37147,-51.7253 -12.37111,-51.72439 -12.37083,-51.72406 -12.37074,-51.72376 -12.37058,-51.72354 -12.37039,-51.72315 -12.3702,-51.72289 -12.37016,-51.72196 -12.36959,-51.72167 -12.36946,-51.72133 -12.36946,-51.72003 -12.36904,-51.71978 -12.36886,-51.71916 -12.36817)))'
```

but when I open this again and try to sloc the same :

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(r'shape/ABCD.shp')
gdf.iloc[0,2]


'MULTIPOLYGON(((-51.71916 -12.36817,-51.71903 -12.36821,-51.71906 -12.36936,-51.71906 -12.37198,-51.71924 -12.37435,-51.71916 -12.37494,-51.72185 -12.37441,-51.72488 -12.37372,-51.72539 -12.37355,-51.72615 -12.37306,-51.72612 -12.37264,-51.726 -12.37222,-'
```

I have no idea why this can happen or how to fix it.

This is also happens outside the function:

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(file_location)
gdf.crs=crs_file

gdf.drop_duplicates(subset=geometry_column,inplace=True)

print(gdf.iloc[0,2])

gdf.to_file('shape/ABCD.shp')

gdf1=gpd.read_file('shape/ABCD.shp')

print(gdf.iloc[0,2])

>>>MULTIPOLYGON(((-51.71916 -12.36817,-51.71903 -12.36821,-51.71906 -12.36936,-51.71906 -12.37198,-51.71924 -12.37435,-51.71916 -12.37494,-51.72185 -12.37441,-51.72488 -12.37372,-51.72539 -12.37355,-51.72615 -12.37306,-51.72612 -12.37264,-51.726 -12.37222,-51.72588 -12.37203,-51.72578 -12.37175,-51.72565 -12.37147,-51.7253 -12.37111,-51.72439 -12.37083,-51.72406 -12.37074,-51.72376 -12.37058,-51.72354 -12.37039,-51.72315 -12.3702,-51.72289 -12.37016,-51.72196 -12.36959,-51.72167 -12.36946,-51.72133 -12.36946,-51.72003 -12.36904,-51.71978 -12.36886,-51.71916 -12.36817)))
MULTIPOLYGON(((-51.71916 -12.36817,-51.71903 -12.36821,-51.71906 -12.36936,-51.71906 -12.37198,-51.71924 -12.37435,-51.71916 -12.37494,-51.72185 -12.37441,-51.72488 -12.37372,-51.72539 -12.37355,-51.72615 -12.37306,-51.72612 -12.37264,-51.726 -12.37222,-
```

My end goal: to drop the duplicates geoemtry and save the result as shapefile correctly

Comment: Can you try to provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: are you looking at the geometries graphically? My guess is that your REPL is truncating the output

Comment: @PaulH what is the REPL? graphically I get lines